# ¿Cómo hacer esta consulta en MongoDB?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, mongodb, nosql

Necesito realizar esta consulta en *MongoDB* para luego implementarla en Java. La idea es que a partir de estos dos documentos, obtener el que en su valor del campo Comuna comienza en `1`, pero omitiendo los dos últimos valores, es decir, `"Comuna:101, Comuna:1001"`, quitar los dos últimos dígitos en memoria, sin modificar el documento, `"Comuna:1, Comuna:10"`, y traer los que sean igual a `1`.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58239b8727365ad4059801bc"),
    "id_publication" : 1478730000,
    "date" : ISODate("2016-11-09T21:56:23.031Z"),
    "author" : 1,
    "weather" : "tempered",
    "Comuna" : "1001"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5823caba2736d607d3bacac2"),
    "id_publication" : 1478740000,
    "date" : ISODate("2016-11-10T01:17:46.048Z"),
    "author" : 1,
    "weather" : "storm",
    "Comuna" : "101"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice esta expresión, espero te sirva:

```
^1([^ ][^ ])$
```

Encuentra coincidencias que inicien con ese carácter(o caracteres) y discrimina a los 2 últimos. Con esto ya te diferencia entre un **1** y un **10**

Saludos!!

Comment: Hola, Gracias Martin, sos Grande!, me funciono tal cual lo necesitaba. entendería que esa expresion regular, divide en dos partes y compara con el valor ^1, pero la pregunta seria que hace que se divida justamente en dos partes donde la 2da contiene los dos ultimos digitos del valor y la otra contiene el valor que necesito comprar... tiene que ver con el operador $. De nuevo te agradezco por tu tiempo. @Martin Mtz

Comment: Si el $ hace que lo que esté dentro del paréntesis sea lo ultimo con lo que va a comparar, eso da paso a que puedas discriminar lo que tú necesites de la parte final de la cadena a evaluar y puedas hacer cualquier comparación antes, en este caso que empiece con cierto carácter(s). Saludos!

Comment: Este regex sólo puede coincidir con strings de 3 caracteres, exclusivamente.

Comment: Es correcto! Pero si reemplazas el 1 por un número dinámico(s), puede funcionar sin problema.

Answer (score 1):

Usa una expresión regular, algo así:

```
db.documento.find({Comuna:{$regex:"^1"});
```

Comment: Hola, justamente la tengo hasta ese punto, la cosa es que en ese punto no me diferencia 101 y 1001, pero por ese lado debe ser, gracias por tu aporte.